# Sed pattern to convert Markdown image style

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a Markdown file with image listings as follows.

> `![Some Text](static/images/image.png)`

Using `sed`, I wish to convert it to the following format, but am not able to figure the correct pattern.

> `![](static/images/image.png){.my-class}`

[***Update***]
A little more context. My Markdown files are like,

> Hello
>   `![Some Text](static/images/image.png)`
>   World

I need to batch convert them to,

> Hello
>   `![](static/images/image.png){.my-class}`
>   World

From other answers on Stackoverflow, I gathered that the pattern `\[[^]]\]` can be used to match square brackets. Using that, I could do the transformation i.e.

> `sed 's,^\!\[[^]]\+\]\(.*\)$,[]\1,g' file.md` --> Works! Gives `[](images/sl/2012-06-18.png)`

But if I append `{.my-class}` towards the end, it messes it up.

> `sed 's,^\!\[[^]]\+\]\(.*\)$,[]\1\{.my-class\},g' file.md` --> doesn't work! Gives `{.my-class}(static/images/image.png)`

So essentially, how can I use `{` in the replace pattern?

Comment: your last command works for me in GNU `sed`, even no need to escape `{` and `}`.

Comment: Please expand on "messes up" and "doesn't work".  What result do you get instead?  Was there an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `sed` command:

```
sed 's/\[[^]]\+\]/[]/;s/$/{.myclass}/' <<< '![Some Text](static/images/image.png)'
```

Comment: Thanks oliv. When run on a file, this didn't work e.g. `sed <your_pattern> file.md`. But works in the form you specified i.e. using a string input. Any idea why?

Comment: What isn't working exactly?

Comment: Executing it on a file is not working . When run on a file (as provided in my update), it doesn't perform replacement correctly. Try it on this file - https://gist.github.com/mohnish82/75f5e3b6e06ae6ce51c01c36bb096374

Comment: works for me, but adds the class to any line, also this replaces every `[...]` which may not be what is expected.

Comment: Figured the problem. The files containing CRLF line endings were producing incorrect output, while LF ones worked correctly. Applying converter pattern (`s|^M$||g`) fixes the issue. Thanks everyone.